# jQuery: getting current selector's inner html PLUS selector's header (outer html)

Tags: jquery-selectors, parent, innerhtml

Using jQuery, I've got a selector -- call it `$('#someDiv1')` -- that I'd like to get the inner HTML for, but also the header of the tag as well. So given this HTML structure..

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    <div id="someDiv1">
        <div id="innerDiv1_1"></div>
        <div id="innerDiv1_2"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="someDiv2">
        <div id="innerDiv2_1"></div>
        <div id="innerDiv2_2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I've got the selector $('#someDiv1') in a variable -- call it $someDiv1 -- I'd like to be able to use that variable to get a string that is:

```
"<div id='someDiv1'>
     <div id='innerDiv1_1'></div>
     <div id='innerDiv1_2'></div>
 </div>"
```

I thought about just saying $someDiv1.parent().html(), but that would give me the div's sibling(s) as well (someDiv2, etc..). Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to ask. What HTML do you want?

Comment: Thought I was pretty clear. If I have a variable called $someDiv1 that is the jQuery selector for the `<div id='someDiv1'>` div, I want the string that I typed out in the question

Answer (score 1):

You also try

```
$('#parentDiv').clone().find("> :not(#someDiv1)").remove().end().html();
```

Comment: +1 Yep - this works - thanks for that. @Julien's one won't work when you have attributes in the div which is what i have ie `class, data-*` etc

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$('<div></div>').append($('#someDiv1').clone()).html()
```